# Drop in traffic in high traffic site after 301 redirect

Tags: seo, google-analytics, 301-redirect, google-adsense, search-results

**Here are the steps I took**

- 301 redirect w/wildcard from old domain to new domain
- Updated & verified Google Search Console for new domain, submitted change of address, etc.
- Updated Google Analytics for new domain
- Added new domain to URL channels and Sites in Google Adsense

**Here are the disastrous results**

- Getting 1/3 of the traffic from before
- Duplicate content in Google search
- It's been 3 days and adsense still hasn't been approved

Starting to panic lol and thinking of a revert / ending the 301's. This is why I delayed this process for so long, too risky. This is a site that was averaging 400k - 500k visitors/mo and and that's not even at peak. I expected 800k at peak - which is 2 weeks from now. I'm losing money. Revenue has dropped to $1/day due to the Google Adsense not being approved yet (if ever??).

What are my options? I thought if you do a 301 redirect everything should go smoothly? Should I wait it out in good faith, adjust something, or abort? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to get Google AdSense approval? You don't need (and shouldn't apply for) a second account.   Your existing account is approved for any domain you wish to use it on.   I routinely run one AdSense account tags on many sites.

Comment: Think I read it on some 301 guide. Why isn't it showing up then do you think? Is URL channel all that's needed?

Comment: I removed the new domain from "Sites" and went back to "URL Channels" and the site is gone from it, but it's not letting me add the new domain anymore. It gives a warning - "You cannot have two channels with the same URL".

Comment: Do you know the proper way to set it up? Should I delete the old domain from Sites and remove the adsense code from old domain?

Comment: Oh, you just added the new site to your sites in your existing account.  Last time I did that, no approval was needed.  It looks like Google is approving sites now maybe.  I added a new site to my account and it was approved in about 6 hours.  Not sure why yours is taking so long.

Comment: Quick info: when you move domains, even with 301 redirects, a drop in ranking/traffic is to be expected. Even happens when just moving from http to https. If you did everything right, it should recover over time but can take a few weeks.

Comment: Ok. Yeah I added the new domain to "Sites" 3-4 days ago, but still in the "Getting Ready" stage. The new domain is now showing in "URL Channels". Should I remove the adsense code from the old domain or keep it?

Comment: `thinking of a revert / ending the 301's.` - if you can do it, do and forget the new domain.

Comment: I think at this point it's been too long so I'm all in on the new domain. So a few days in, things are looking a little better. Some of the top keywords are starting to come around with the new domain and ranking ok in google, so some link juice appears to be working, although traffic is still down maybe around 30-40%. Main thing now is Google Adsense still not working. I'm not going to wait for Google, I've contacted other ad networks.

Comment: Update: Adsense back today. Just took awhile. It looks like the 301's are finally working and a lot of good seo ranking again in google.Thanks for help!